# Why does $\aleph_{\omega}$ have more than $\aleph_{\omega}$ countable subsets?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I believe  $\aleph_{\omega}$ has more than $\aleph_{\omega}$ countable subsets but I do not see the proof.  I fear it is obvious, but not to me today.

Comment: Yes, this follows from König's Theorem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29


Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_\omega\}$ be all countable subsets of $\omega_\omega$. We build one that is not among them, giving the contradiction. Pick $x_0\in\omega_1$ wich is not in $\bigcup\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega\}$. Then choose $\omega_1\leq x_1<\omega_2$ which is not in $\bigcup\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$, etc. Eventually we get a countable set 
$\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}$ different from each $A_\alpha$. (This is essentially the argument for proving Konig's inequality.)

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  Since you have shown it to me, Konig's inequality will be obvious to me from now on.